# Set numeric labels on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a graph using `ggplot2` to illustrate a linear model I ran.

The x axis represents a score a group of students received on a test. The test score could range from -218 to +218 points. When I create my graph, however, the x axis automatically shows the numbers -200 and 200, but I would like to use the labels -218 and 218 instead, since they are more informative in this case (because those were the "limits").

This is the graph I created:
[image]

I tried using `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,20), xlim = c(-218,218))` as well as `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-218,218))`, but none of those options works, even though they do work for the y axis.

Any ideas on how I can get the output I want?

Comment: please share a reproducible example of your data and the exact code you made to produce the figure. thanks.

Comment: If you read the help page for `scale_continuous`, they include two relevant options: `breaks=` (which defines *where* the axis ticks go), and `labels=` (defines how they look).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead setting the breaks manually by passing a vector of  desired breaks, e.g. `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-218,-100,0,100,218))` (as suggested by @r2evans).

However, consider using breaks with more natural spacing, e.g. from -220 to 220, and if you need to highlight the boundaries at 218 consider using a vertical line.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = runif(min = -218, max = 218, n = 100),
           y = rnorm(n = 100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-218,218), linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-220,220,40)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `seq(-218,218,by=100)` does not include both ends, you should likely either control it manually (e.g., `breaks=c(-218,-100,0,100,218)`) or append +/- 218 onto another vector.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @r2evans, would you be so kind as to suggest an edit or post it as an answer?

Comment: Nawww, I'm still waiting for your unfinished sentence ;-)

Comment: That will teach me to answer questions on the phone, sorry for the poor quality answer @aprendiz, I've updated it now to add some more clarity.